# Multiple Selection in php query

Tags: php

I have a sample code here which the multiple selection.
Now my question is how can i get this multiple data, then display it through mysql query in php.

Please help me!.
Thank you!

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="display.php">
      <table width="300" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Multiple Selection </label>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><select name="select2" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
            <option value="RAY 1">RAY 1</option>
            <option value="RAY 2">RAY 2</option>
            <option value="RAY 3">RAY 3</option>
            <option value="KALSADA">KALSADA</option>
            <option value="ROAD">ROAD</option>
            <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
            <option value="SA">SALINTUBIG</option>
            <option value="CMGP">CMGP</option>
            <option value="PAMANA">PAMANA</option>
            <option value="LGSF">LGSF</option>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select should be as follows (note the square brackets):

```
<select name="select2[]" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
```

In your PHP code you can get the data for the selected options as follows:

```
$data = $_GET['select2'];
```

You can turn the array $data into a comma separated list for use with your SQL query as follows:

```
$list = "'" . implode("','" , $data) . "'";
```

You can then use this comma separated list in your SQL query as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE program IN ($list)"
```

Comment: can i do the same in another column? with different input name or variable?

Comment: Do you mean more than one column in the same query?

Comment: Yes can i do that?, i tried but warning appeared like this Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\LFP\samlist.php

Comment: Because id like to filter per column with this multiple seletion

Comment: You can use the $list variable with more than one column in your SQL query using the AND operator. 

For example, if you had a column called 'another' then you could do the following:

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM lfpstatustable1 WHERE program IN ($list) AND another IN ($list)";

Comment: Can i do this?      $year = $_GET['year'];
                      $yearlist = "'" . implode("','" , $year) . "'";

                      $stat = $_GET['stat'];
                      $statlist = "'" . implode("','" , $stat) . "'";

Comment: Or can i use more variable inside implode?

Comment: I assume year, stat, etc. are separate select lists and part of the same html form.  If so, then yes you can do that and use each variable in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
name="select2"
```

To,

```
name="select2[]"
```

That will allow you pass multiples values from the HTML form to the PHP.

Then, in your PHP code you'll receive an array of of values (`$_GET['select2']`) which can be used either in a loop or they can be [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)d and used in a `IN`.